# Td horizontal overlapping

Tags: css, html-table, overlap

I have a horizontal menu with 7 menu-items. The menu is one table, with one row, with 7 cells.

The right-border of the cells is a light color. The left-border of the cell is a dark color.

What I now want is that the right-border of cell one is right of the left-border of cell two. The dark border (of cell 2)will then be left and the light border (of cell 1) will be right.

**Problem:** `margin-left:-2%;` doesn't work! And `margin-right:-2%;` not too! And `left` and `right` not, and pixels  not! How can I let the cells overlap, and why don't these things work

Comment: Just a suggestion. You shouldn't use tables for design/layout.

Comment: In this case, it is the least worse thing.

Comment: I don't think cells can overlap. If you could post a sample of your CSS and HTML, it would be easier to suggest ways/alternates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells cannot overlap for sure. But you can change your ordering a bit:

your odd cells can have light borders and your even cells can have dark borders such that the effect remains same.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't know that cells could not overlap. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think table cells can overlap. A better solution would be to use a list rather than a table (which is what you should be doing anyway). Then you can style the li elements.

E.g.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>First menu item</li>
  <li>Second menu item</li>
  <li>Third menu item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li { 
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC; }

li:first-child { border-left: none; }
li:last-child { border-right: none; }
```